# Firebug like autocomplete css editor

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know a css(or html) editor that autocompletes code as firebug do in css?
I think its called autocomplete as you type.

thanks

**edit:**

i found a project called zen-coding that create shortcuts for coding html and css. but im still faster with firebug

Answer (score 1):

Most decent IDEs should offer autocomplete on any language they support.

I'm using Netbeans here, and I can confirm it gives me autocomplete on the various languages I'm using, including HTML and CSS.

http://netbeans.org/

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org), and most major IDEs have a "code assist" feature that propose the possiblities on a hot key (eg., `ctrl+space`) or on a specific event (press `<`) or on a timeout (most of these are configurable).

[Aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/) is a eclipse based IDE for web development.

If you are specifically looking for "firebug style" meaning you expect the IDE to auto-complete (rather than *propose*) then you can tweak the options to get a similar behaviour ("completion Overwrites" rather than "Completion Inserts", for eclipse)

Comment: how can i tweak that options?

Comment: @Rafalages, what exactly you want? Also did you already try Eclipse or any other IDE?

Comment: im using on eclipse with aptana, when u said 'tweak' do you mean 'edit souce code of a editor or create a plugin for it'?

Comment: What i meant was: In Eclipse, you can tweak some of the options in window->preferences. Something like "auto propose changes", "proposals overwrites rather than inserts" so that you get a *similar* (though not exactly same) behaviour as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Or try cssUpdater, which syncs your FireBug css changes back to your original css files. 
With it, you can construct and tweak you layout in FireBug, hit the sync button and reload the page to see that your layout and css is preserved.  http://cssupdater.com

Answer (score 0):

The best firebug-alike approach apps is : http://www.stylizerapp.com/

It's available on PC and Mac too.